# Router link giving warning " link is a void element tag and must not have `children` or use `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`."

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-route first time.
when i am trying this, it gives me this warning and its not working 
"Warning: link is a void element tag and must not have `children` or use `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of Loginpanel."

my code is like this.

```
render() {

    return (

        <div >

            <input type="email" />
            <input type="password"/><br/>

         <link to="Index">   BLOCK
         </link>

        </div>

       )
    }
  }
```

and my main main.js is like this

```
    render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>

      <Route path="/" component={Loginpanel} >
    <Route path="Index" component={App}/>
      <Route path="Form" component={Form} />
          </Route>


    </Router>,
   document.getElementById('js-main'));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` its **Link** and not link. Can you try that once?

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
```

and

```
<Link to="Index">BLOCK</Link>
```

Comment: if it was that funny you could have put Link instead of link, just trying to help

Comment: i am sorry./. you were right.. <Link> was mistake.. first time. i didnt read your comment... i am accepting your answer and giving you point man,... thanks lot buddy

Comment: Yep, that was my issue. Spent a good 15 minutes debugging before finding this.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that helps me also

Answer (score 15):

Change the `link` to `Link`

The first letter is Capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react-router version 4 then this is the right way to import Link

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

because the React Router project has now been broken up into a couple of different libraries

Answer (score 1):

In complement of Harkirat Saluja answer:

**render method example:**

```
render() {

    return (

        <div>
          <Link to="Index">It Link, not link </Link>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// import link and inside div, the {L} shod be capital later

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

render() {

```
return (
   <div>
      <Link to="Index">It Link, not link </Link>
   </div>
);
```

}