# What is the best process of adding Routers to a web page in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

×
Error: link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
▶ 14 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
C:/Users/HP/Desktop/portfolio-project/portfolio-project/src/index.js:11
8 |
9 | const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
10 |

> 11 | ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById("root"));
> 12 |
> 13 | //ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById("super"))
> 14 | //ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById("root"))
> View compiled
> **webpack_require**
> C:/Users/HP/Desktop/portfolio-project/portfolio-project/webpack/bootstrap:782
> 779 | };
> 780 |
> 781 | // Execute the module function
> 782 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
> | ^  783 |
> 784 | // Flag the module as loaded
> 785 | module.l = true;

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import About from './Components/About';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';

import {
    BrowserRouter as Router, 
    Routes, 
    Route, 
    Link
 } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className='App'>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <link to="/">Home</link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <link to="/about">About Us</link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <link to="/contact">Contact Us</link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />}> </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/about' element={<About />}> </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/contact' element={<Contact />}> </Route>
                </Routes>
            
        </Router>
    );
   
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Router link giving warning " link is a void element tag and must not have \`children\` or use \`props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML\`."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806260/router-link-giving-warning-link-is-a-void-element-tag-and-must-not-have-child)

Comment: You've a typo. Use the `Link` component, not a `link` element. Voting to close with "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying changing the link to "Link"

```
 <Link to="/contact" >Contact</Link>
```

Comment: That was easy, I'm really glad, being a beginner is stressful all I need is actually here on stack overflow

Comment: Glad I was able to help a bit, Good luck